# Output sentences in order in Java

Tags: java, string, file, for-loop, arraylist

I'm currently trying to get this output where the sentences in the text file are in order:

```
0 : The cat in the hat
1 : The cat sat on the mat
2 : Pigs in a blanket
```

I added the text file into an `ArrayList` and currently having trouble displaying the above output. I know the problem lies somewhere in the `for loop`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

        //Pass in file name as command line argument
        File inFile = new File("test.txt");

        //Open scanner to scan in the file and create Array List
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(inFile))) 
        {
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();


        //Create while loop to read in sentences of the file
            while(scan.hasNextLine())
            {
                String line = scan.nextLine();
                list.add(line);
            }

           int i;
            System.out.println("Input Sentences: ");
            for(i = 0; i<inFile.length(); i++)
            {
                System.out.println(i + ":");
            } 

        }


}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not writing the contents to output. Do something like this:

```
 for(i = 0; i<list.size(); i++)
 {
     System.out.println(i + ":" + list.get(i));
 }
```

Comment: My pleasure. However, using two loops won't be a really good approach. You could display contents in the while loop itself. In that case, you wouldn't need an ArrayList either (unless you want to store the contents, so that you could reuse them later).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to display what is in the arraylist, so change the for loop to look like:

```
       for(i = 0; i<list.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i + " : " + list.get(i));
        }
```